# Line Break in TextBox or Html Area

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

What is the way of separating Line-Breaks and Space in MultiLine Textbox or HTML Text area while inserting database (Asp.Net). For example what should I do if I want to insert

Hello

World

to database with line breaks?  And also While displaying what should I do?  I don't want to use Editor for it.

---

But the problem is how to seperate line break and space.  Now when I insert

Hello

World

or hello world, it is saved with same character in the database.  Therefore I can't separate them and I am showing hello world although user uses line breaks such as above. The value, which comes from TextBox or html area, are the same as with line break or space.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The line breaks should persist to the db.  When you retreive the info and display as Html just replace the line break (i.e. Environment.NewLine) with a line break tag (i.e.  `< b r / >` )

Comment: Don't forget to Html.Encode() first, then do the Replace() if it's user submitted content.

Comment: You ought to use HtmlEncode() *always*, whether the content is user-enetered or not. All it takes is one accidentally inserted `<` or `'` to really mess things up.

Answer (score 6):

`< br />` didnt work for me. (while assigning text to html textarea)

`\r\n` did.

Answer (score 4):

Using Razor (MVC3), to display or preserve line breaks pulled from my db, the following works:

```
@Html.Raw(text_to_display.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use &#10;

Comment: No, you can't. Spaces are (mostly) ignored in HTML. He needs to use an actual formatting line-break, which is `&lt;br/&gt;`.

Comment: You're right. I thought he was asking about adding line breaks to the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

A few choices:
• Convert newlines to `<br/>`.
• Put your text in a `<pre>` block.
• Put each line in its own `<div>` block.

Remember, all whitespace (SP, HT, LF, CR) is ignored in HTML (most of the time).

What you store in your database should be the pure character text. Converting it into proper HTML for display requires replacing certain characters with HTML sequences.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to keep formatted carriage returns / new lines for a textarea control on asp.net page that gets it value from the code behind you should use:

```
textarea.Value = Server.HtmlDecode(myValue.Replace("\r\n", "&#13;"));
```

This will render from:

```
some blah blah\r\nblah blah
```

to:

```
some blah blah
blah blah
```

So when you use javascript to read for line breaks you can use:

```
textarea.value.indexOf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I always store user input as it is provided, but then you must always be **very careful** when displaying it back again. Line breaks are simply a case of replacing System.Environment.Newline with "<br />". Not sure what the best practice is for preserving other white space when rendered as html, would be interesting to hear what other people do.

Answer (score 0):

Retaining white space after rendering to HTML is most easily done by converting it into the HTML entity `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all instances of vbcrlf (environment.newline) with the html tag [< b r >]

And to allow multiple spaces you need to replace space with [& n b s p ;]

That will convert your plain test to html "enough" to be viewed as html (works for me on the entered text sections of my web site)

From my tags it's only the text between the [] and remove the spaces ... placing the tag text into the page caused it to be displayed as the html !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion above that worked for me was:  `<& # 1 0 ;>`
I am using a text box generated by Front Page now running on a Linux server.

Multiple uses of the string will not create multiple line breaks, but a single entry of the string on a new line provides a double line break suitable for a new paragraph.

Before moving my page from a server using a Windows OS, I was able to accomplish Line Breaks by double "Enters."