# ASP.NET saving text to database in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web, plugins

I have an ASP.net 4.5 text box with 5 rows. When I save the below data to my table it does not take in consideration that there are line breaks.

Example:

> Hello my name is Mike! 
>   How are you?
>
> Please can you help?

When saving this data to my table it of course save it like this below and it will be displayed like this again if I populate my website with this value.

> Hello my name is Mike!How are you?Please can you help?

But I want it to be displayed with the line breaks as the way it was written in the first place.

The thing is, I do not want to make use of a custom form item because then the user will be able to copy and paste all html from another website in and I do not want that.

Any idea how this can be done without using a plugin such as below where the user will be able to copy and paste data into?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296849/line-break-in-textbox-or-html-area  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883613/asp-net-text-with-linebreak-from-multi-line-textbox-to-save-in-a-database  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536431/save-the-value-from-multiline-textbox-into-sql-server-with-line-brea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To populate your text box from the database try;

```
TextBox1.Text = someText.Replace("\r\n", Environment.NewLine)
```

For Label

```
Label1.Text = someText.Replace("\r\n", <br />)
```

Alternatively you could save the data to your database with the

```
someText = TextBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
```

Although this approach may not be appropriate if the database is also used elsewhere.